# How to make button do 2 events?

Tags: android

I'm making an application and it has a button in it which I wish to do these things on being pressed:

1. call a toast
2. change text color in a textview

How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Please post code what you have tried so far

Comment: Simply call the methods in sequence in the click listener.

Comment: 2 events like ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

```
  Button btn;

  btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "abc....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         mTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#bdbdbd"));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Android", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            yourtextview.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff00"));
        }
    });
```